# EntitySqlException in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4

I am working through the [Programming Entity Framework, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596807252.do) book, the example using `Entity SQL`.  Changing the name of the context in the example and altering the line

```
ObjectQuery<Contact> contacts = context.CreateQuery<Contact>(queryString);
```

to

```
ObjectQuery<Contact> objectQuery = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<Contact>(QUERY_STRING);
```

I get this:

```
using (var context = new PROGRAMMINGEFDBEntities())
{
    const string QUERY_STRING = "SELECT VALUE c" +
                                "FROM PROGRAMMINGEFDBEntities.Contacts AS c " +
                                "WHERE c.FirstName='Robert'";
    ObjectQuery<Contact> objectQuery = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<Contact>(QUERY_STRING);
    foreach (var contact in objectQuery)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", contact.FirstName, contact.LastName);
    }
}
```

When it is run, I get the following exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntitySqlException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232006
  Message=The query syntax is not valid. Near identifier 'PROGRAMMINGEFDBEntities', line 1, column 20.
  Source=EntityFramework
  Column=20
  ErrorContext=identifier 'PROGRAMMINGEFDBEntities', line 1, column 20
  ErrorDescription=The query syntax is not valid.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a Space after

```
"SELECT VALUE c "
```